# ssh config for multiple ssh keys

Tags: ssh

I have the following ssh config file:

```
Host git.github.com
                User git
                IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host git.assembla.com
                User git
                IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_assembla
Host XXX.XXX.XXXX.group
                IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_gerrit
                User xxxx
```

But when I try and log in, I get:

> Unable to negotiate with XX.XXX.XXX.XXX port XXXX: no matching key
>   exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key exchange method `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` is obsolete. You should update your server to support something more recent.

To connect to this host, you can workaround it by setting

```
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

to your `Host` block in `ssh_config`, as described in the official [Legacy page](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html) on OpenSSH.